# Access the active bookmark name without parsing a command output?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-api

I'd like to automatically add the active bookmark name (if any) to the commit message.

I found [this method](http://www.hascode.com/2012/12/creating-pre-commit-hooks-in-git-and-mercurial-prefix-commit-messages-for-featurestory-branches/) to do something similar as a pre-commit hook. However it uses the branch name, which is redundant since named branches are part of metadata. I would like the active bookmark instead.

The internal API context used in this example does not seem to hold bookmark info (see [MercurialApi](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialApi#Change_contexts)). Using [hglib](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PythonHglib) I could get the result of `hg bookmarks`, then parse it, find the line with `*`, trim to the right column... that's ugly.

I understand that hg lacks the equivalent of git's "plumbing" commands, but I can't even find a python API that offers what I'm looking for.

Are bookmarks managed by the internal API (if so, where is the doc?) or how can I avoid the parsing solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use python-hglib:

```
import hglib
client = hglib.open('.')
bookmarks, active = client.bookmarks()
if active == -1:
    print 'no active bookmark'
else:
    print 'active bookmark:', bookmarks[active][0]
```

The confusion might be that the API documented on the MercurialAPI wiki page is the *internal* API. The API provided by python-hglib is apparently not really documented anywhere except in the code of the library. The [`bookmarks` method](http://selenic.com/repo/python-hglib/file/cc905ee18449/hglib/client.py#l376) is documented, for example.

Answer (score 1):

For command-line usage / shell hooks, use this command, which prints either the active bookmark name or an empty string.

```
hg log -r . -T '{activebookmark}'
```

The active bookmark is always on the current commit (otherwise it would be inactive). The log template variable `activebookmark` prints the active bookmark (if associated with the changeset). You'll get exit code 0 (success) whether there is an active bookmark or not, but the printed string will differ. Example session:

```
$ hg bookmark myfeature
$ hg log -r . -T '{activebookmark}'
myfeature
$ hg bookmark --inactive
$ hg log -r . -T '{activebookmark}'

$ # We got an empty line.
```

Answer (score 0):

`hg id -B` in case of existing bookmark return bookmark-name only, nothing - if bookmark doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks, but I just checked that if there are two bookmarks, changing the active one won't change the output of `hg id -B`.

Answer (score 0):

Following Martin Geisler answer and [this post](http://www.hascode.com/2012/12/creating-pre-commit-hooks-in-git-and-mercurial-prefix-commit-messages-for-featurestory-branches/), here is a hook that works on Windows:

in `hgrc`:

```
[hooks]
precommit.bookmark = python:/path/to/hg-hooks.py:prefix_commit_message
```

and in `hg-hooks.py`:

```
import sys, mercurial

## to be accepted in TortoiseHg, see http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.9/faq.html
sys.path.append(r'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages')
import hglib

def _get_active_bookmark(path):
    '''Return the active bookmark or None.
    '''
    client = hglib.open(path)
    bookmarks, active = client.bookmarks()
    if active == -1:
        return None
    else:
        return bookmarks[active][0]


###
### Available hooks
###

def prefix_commit_message(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    '''Prepend [active bookmark name] to commit message.
    '''
    commitctx = repo.commitctx

    def rewrite_ctx(ctx, error):
        book = _get_active_bookmark(repo.root)
        if book:
            old_text = ctx._text
            if not old_text.lstrip().startswith("["):
                ctx._text = "[" + book + "] "+ old_text
        return commitctx(ctx, error)

    repo.commitctx = rewrite_ctx
```